# Mount Azure Storage Container to Databricks Workspace / Notebook results in AttributeError

Tags: python, databricks, azure-keyvault, azure-databricks, azure-secrets

I'm trying to mount an Azure Blob Storage Container to a Databricks workbook using a Key Vault-backed secret scope.

**Setup:**

1. Created a Key Vault
2. Created a Secret in Key Vault
3. Created a Databricks Secret Scope

- This is known-good.

  - Running `dbutils.secrets.get(scope = dbrick_secret_scope, key = dbrick_secret_name)` results in no errors
  - Viewing the secret in Databricks results in `[REDACTED]`

**Cell in Databricks:**

```
%python

dbrick_secret_scope = "dbricks_kv_dev"
dbrick_secret_name = "scrt-account-key"

storage_account_key = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = dbrick_secret_scope, key = dbrick_secret_name)
storage_container = 'abc-test'
storage_account = 'stgdev'

dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = f'abfss://{storage_container}@{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net/',
    mount_point = f'/mnt/{storage_account}',
    extra_configs = {f'fs.azure.accountkey.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net:{storage_account_key}'}
)
```

**Results:**

- Error: `AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'keys'` with the `mount_point` line of `dbutils.fs.mount()` highlighted in red.
- Full error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3166320686381550> in <module>
      9     source = f'abfss://{storage_container}@{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net/',
     10     mount_point = f'/mnt/{storage_account}',
---> 11     extra_configs = {f'fs.azure.accountkey.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net:{storage_account_key}'}
     12 )

/local_disk0/tmp/1625601199293-0/dbutils.py in f_with_exception_handling(*args, **kwargs)
    298             def f_with_exception_handling(*args, **kwargs):
    299                 try:
--> 300                     return f(*args, **kwargs)
    301                 except Py4JJavaError as e:
    302                     class ExecutionError(Exception):

/local_disk0/tmp/1625601199293-0/dbutils.py in mount(self, source, mount_point, encryption_type, owner, extra_configs)
    389                 self.check_types([(owner, string_types)])
    390             java_extra_configs = \
--> 391                 MapConverter().convert(extra_configs, self.sc._jvm._gateway_client)
    392             return self.print_return(self.dbcore.mount(source, mount_point,
    393                                                        encryption_type, owner,

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_collections.py in convert(self, object, gateway_client)
    520         HashMap = JavaClass("java.util.HashMap", gateway_client)
    521         java_map = HashMap()
--> 522         for key in object.keys():
    523             java_map[key] = object[key]
    524         return java_map

AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Appears to be related to the `extra_configs` parameters, but I'm not exactly sure what. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Real error in your case is that you need to provide dictionary as `extra_configs` argument, but you're providing the set: `{f'fs.azure.accountkey.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net:{storage_account_key}'}` - this happens because you don't have correct syntax (two `'` are missing). Correct syntax will be: `{f'fs.azure.accountkey.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net':storage_account_key}`

But really you can't mount with `abfss` protocol by using the storage account key - it's only supported for mounting with `wasbs` protocol.  For `abfss` you **must** use service principal, and provide it's ID & secret, like this (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access#---mount-adls-gen2-storage)):

```py
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "<application-id>",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope-name>",key="<service-credential-key-name>"),
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token"}

dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
  extra_configs = configs)
```

And although you theoretically can mount the ADLS Gen2 storage using the `wasbs` protocol and storage key, it's not recommended as you can get problems (I hit that personally).  Also, it's not recommended to use storage keys, it's better to use Shared Access Signature instead - it's more secure.

Comment: Thank you for the details. This is helpful. I'm not seeing in your `Correct syntax...` where the two missing `'` are.

Comment: your problem was that you were missed the closing `'` after `windows.net`, so everything was considered as a one string, and `{`, and `}` around single element and this syntax is used for Python sets